# What's a great christmas present for someone with a PhD in Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question

Christmas is **just around the corner** and I haven't bought all the gifts for my family yet ( yeah, )
My Dad has a PhD in Mathematics, he works in Graph theory and his thesis was about Quasiperiodic tilings.
What do you think would make a good gift for him?
I'll appreciate anything you could think of!
Thanks for reading, hope you have a great day .

p.s.: after reading all the tags in this website I think this is the right one for this kind of question? please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: This should obviously be CW, but I support this question existing in the hope that my future children will get me cool math gifts.

Comment: I personally would love to have a Math book as a gift. But it is tricky, as your father probably has a good collection of books.

Comment: This is entirely not the right website, but I’d like to see what answers you get anyway, so let’s hope the “vote-to-closers” are too busy closing homework questions and let this one survive at least for a while.

Comment: Any sort of puzzle of the Rubik's cube type should be pretty good, where you have to assemble, disassemble, entangle, disentangle something or other.

Comment: I was going to recommend this book, but alas it is sold out. https://www.fondationcartier.com/en/editions/mathematiques-un-depaysement-soudain

Comment: Please, keep this question open. It is one of a very few holidays treats we can have in MathOverflow in the depressing time we have.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz, amen.

Comment: Expanding on the Rubik's cube idea: if you know your father enjoys solving the classic 3x3x3 cube, the smallest version of the dodecahedron puzzle only requires the same algorithms as the 3x3x3 cube, so it's really fun and it's a *beautiful* piece of work.

Comment: Bottle of really good whisky, a Japanese hand made carbon steel gyuto, a house. All great Christmas gifts from the point of view of this PhD in mathematics.

Comment: You can buy a "Hilbert Hat"! ((:

Comment: Are you sure that Dad is not an MO regular?

Comment: @user347489: Incidentally, mathematicians who know how to derive the solution for a Rubik's cube typically also [can solve most common permutation puzzles](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820), so those who are like me would consider all those puzzles as nothing new. But [the Square-1 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-1_%28puzzle%29) is a more sneaky type.

Comment: My 101 score is not enough to answer here... GET A 3D PRINTER AND COPY SOME OF THESE TO 3D https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=math+art&type=things&sort=relevant&category_id=79&page=1

Comment: Am I allowed to go against the grain and suggest *not* getting your dad a math-related gift? Maybe I am not "mathy" enough but I usually find such gifts a bit boring/easily forgotten (ok, I love the suggestion below about Hagaromo chalk!)

Comment: I was going to answer your title question with "cash" but I guess that's not appropriate seeing as it's for your dad.

Comment: @user21820: I'd be happy with a square-1 puzzle for a present. It looks cool!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add an answer, but [The Mathematical Expericence](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Experience-Philip-J-Davis/dp/0817637397/ref=smi_www_rco2_go_smi_g1285150262?_encoding=UTF8&%2AVersion%2A=1&%2Aentries%2A=0&ie=UTF8) was a book I very much enjoyed when I was an undergraduate.

Comment: I do not have enough points to provide a real answer, but how about a Paul Erdos biography: https://www.amazon.de/Man-Who-Loved-Only-Numbers/dp/0786884061

Comment: I love https://www.youtube.com/user/standupmaths and Matt Parker wrote a bunch of books about math problems, misunderstandings and failures.

Answer (score 98):

I'm surprised no one has yet suggested a lifetime supply of Hagoromo chalk.

Comment: Sadly, those of us who already purchased a lifetime supply (well, a 10 year supply) haven't been able to use it while teaching remotely on our iPads. :(

Comment: @Joe: Not with that attitude...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, not quite sure what "attitude" you're attributing to my post. It was meant to partly reflect sadness that such a gift wouldn't be of immediate use, with an underlying unexpressed hope for the future that by the following Christmas we'll be back in the classroom and reunited with our students. But as always, it can be difficult to exactly convey one's meaning in a short online comment. And BTW, I think Deane's suggestion for a gift is excellent.

Comment: @Joe: That's a joke, suggesting that you're expecting to fail using the chalk with an iPad. It's a common joke, e.g. "I don't think I can eat a 2kg steak.", "Not with this attitude you can't.", etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, I see, that completely went by me. Makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: You can always make your own chalks in your kitchen. Artists make their own pastels at home. In Youtube, there are videos on recipes for soft pastels. Experienced artists might know what ingredients are gone into making Hagoromo chalks, if they test them.

Comment: I googled online as to the ingredients. I see that there is another brand that is Umajirushi,  the nearest rival to Hagoromo. Both use calcium carbonate to minimise dusting. I guess the rest of ingredients might be titanium dioxide (opaque soft white pigment), plaster of Paris, etc. If you want colouring, use watercolour paints. Specks from Cotman paints will suffice. Add binding agent. https://www.amazon.com/Kedudes-Non-Toxic-Dustless-Colored-Chalkboard/dp/B010BTLTSG/ref=sr_1_3?crid=N2MUZ2M6FNB9&dchild=1&keywords=umajirushi%2Bchalk&qid=1607786227&sprefix=Umajirushi%2B%2Caps%2C250&sr=8-3&th=1

Comment: To make chalks, you can find many ingredients at good art stores for professional artists and paint makers. They would have all the ingredients that are used to make Hagoromo chalks. They would have books & videos on making soft pastels.

Comment: @JoeSilverman - you can still use chalk on your iPad. Admittedly, it's a little messy...:-)

Comment: @RitaGeraghty, if you happen to try this yourself and it works out well, please post the recipe.

Comment: @DeaneYang I remember watching my art professor teaching students how to make all his own paints and pastels. Here is the video. You have to experiment with ratios of ingredients and achieve whatever you want in chalks. Here is the video showing how to make art pastel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRMi24FasHI You may have to change ingredients for chalk making. For colouring chalks, use kids' non-staining poster paints instead of powdered pigments. Decide the ratios of calcium carbonate and plaster of Paris. More calcium carbonate to reduce dustiness in chalks. To shape chalks, use a funnel

Comment: @DeaneYang. If you want opaque whiteness and smoothest grains in your chalks, go for the most finely grounded powder of titanium dioxide, which you can find it at most professional art stores. Most artists buy that white pigment in bulk, as it is the most used pigment on palettes, especially for mixing colours with. For binders, you can use wallpaper paste or paper gum or Arabic gum. You probably won't paste or gum if plaster of Paris can binds all ingredients together. If you are in UK, visit Russell & Chapple, or Dick Blick if you are in USA or whatever your favourite art stores.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty, truth is that few of us will have the patience to figure out the optimal recipe. There are other features such as a coating on the outside of the chalk to reduce the amount of chalk dust produced. Here's New York Times story about the chalk that shows some of the manufacturing process. https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/17/world/asia/hagoromo-chalk.html

Comment: @DeaneYang There are edible chalks that you can buy or make your own. If they are edible, they can't be toxic. Recipes are available at Youtube. Some people make edible chalks with flour, cornflour, icing sugar, etc, but well, they mightn't be as good as Hagoromo chalks.

Answer (score 84):

Obviously, a [closed, non-orientable, boundary-free manifold](https://www.kleinbottle.com/).

Comment: I can confirm that this is a good answer. A former high school math teacher I know keeps his copy on display in the kitchen.

Comment: I also confirm, and used this many times for all kinds of gifts to mathematicians. They also have scarfs, knit hats and many other non-orientable things for sail.

Comment: THE CUCKOO'S EGG!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: My wife bought one of these for me, and I can confirm that it is a good gift (I'm not even in math, I'm in computer science). Before she bought it, she asked my brother if it was a good idea and he said, "of course!" She asked, "but what's the point of it?" He replied, "that it's a Klein Bottle."

Comment: if you're really cheap you can turn the label of an e.g. water bottle into a Moebius strip.

Comment: There's a Klein bottle opener.

Comment: Well, at least a projection of it...

Comment: I prefer an [edible, non-healthy, sugar-full torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doughnut).

Comment: I had one of these, but my sister took it to her school for a show and tell day without my permission, and I was returned a box full of glass shards.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Acme-Klein-Bottle-Handmade-Glass/dp/B017UY60MK Are there more symmetrical Klein bottles than this one (which everybody has seen a million times)?

Answer (score 41):

Bit expensive, but a Gömböc might be a nice desk toy...

Added: the on-demand 3D-printing site shapeways has a category for mathematical art

https://www.shapeways.com/marketplace/art/mathematical-art

One of these is a model of the generalised hexagon of order 2, due to my close colleague John Bamberg. (I get no commission if you buy one.)

https://www.shapeways.com/product/QZP8BGTE2/generalised-hexagon-of-order-2

The bipartite incidence graph of this geometry has diameter 6 and girth 12 and 126 vertices and is often called Tutte’s 12-cage, so it rates highly on “graph-theory content”.

Comment: If they ship many of these... things... I wonder what is the plural of gömböc :)

Comment: Well, the internet tells me: Gömböcök.

Answer (score 40):

This is not out yet, so it would a present for Christmas 2021 and beyond, but this coffee table book of photographs of mathematicians' chalkboards looks very, very cool:  [Jessica Wynne, "Do Not Erase: Mathematicians and Their Chalkboards"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691199221/do-not-erase).

EDIT:

It is published now.

Comment: Oh that looks wonderful ...

Comment: You can see some preview images here: https://www.thisiscolossal.com/2019/10/mathematicians-chalkboards-by-jessica-wynne/

Comment: Here’s another story about the book: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/23/science/mathematicians-blackboard-photographs-jessica-wynne.html

Comment: Jessica’s web site. https://jessicawynne.com/

Answer (score 28):

The **Museum of Mathematics gift shop** has possibly the most well-curated collection  I know of.  It features so many things that I'd want and so few that I actually need, and that's practically the definition of a good gift.

https://shop.momath.org

Answer (score 25):

A mathematical gift that I enjoyed was a triple of solids of constant width.

[image]

Comment: I imagine these feel very nice to roll around in your hand together.  I imagine that you don't really have a sensation of one rolling over the "edge" of the other because of the constant width?  I would be very curious to play with these.

Comment: The nice thing is to put a book on three of them and see how it stays stable and parallel to the floor. When I got the gift it did not work for me because I missed one of the solids in the box and tried it on two.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I've never held these, but I imagine you'd still feel it as you roll over an "edge" - constant width does not imply that the center of mass is at the geometric center, so you could still have differently stable positions depending on the orientation. The top right image, for example, looks like it's sitting stably on its base, but would fall stably to the bottom right image if tipped far enough over the "edge", so I think you'd feel it behave differently as you rotate it. I'm also very curious for hands-on experience.

Answer (score 23):

Nate Eldredge will generate a random mathematical paper for you (with authors of your choice) for free or you can order a printed randomly generated book (I’m unsure whether these can be personalized). See [his blog here.](https://thatsmathematics.com/blog/mathgen-books/). He will donate $5 to the AMS for all books sold.)

Answer (score 18):

I figured someone would mention this, but since no one has, I will. If our dad likes mathematical history in a personal vein, the Math Genealogy Project will create a personalized history of his mathematical predecessors, PhD advisor by PhD advisor, with some branching. And if he's had PhD students of his own, those can be included. One of my colleagues has a framed one on his wall and it's always fun to look at. In many cases, the trail goes back to the 18th century, or even earlier.

https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/posters.php

Comment: Great suggestion!

Comment: This. My (former) grad students jointly got me one for hitting 50. In Notre Dame colors, too. I think they overdid it a bit, getting back to Erasmus of Rotterdam is a bit much. But it is still very nice. Keeping it in my office. Framed.

Answer (score 17):

**A fountain pen**, of course. If you do mathematics you have to write a lot. I write about 6,000 pages per year (I know it is crazy that I know that number) and the the best writing tool ever created is a fountain pen. My father gave me my first fountain pen when I was 12 and now I have more than 30 of them. I poisoned my kids with the love to fountain pens too, but they are jealous, because they think I might love fountain pens more then them, and I will not comment on that. Merry Christmas!

Comment: What kind would you recommend?

Comment: This heavily depends on each individual. I would personally pick a cheap bic pen to work with over a fountain pen 24/7/365 (even 366 if it comes down to it).

Comment: @user347489 Are you left-handed?

Comment: To add to user347489's caveat, there are also people like me, who strongly prefer pencils. For them I'd recommend a good mechanical pencil or a good pencil sharpener. In any case, do your research on the individual before spending to much money on something like this.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: For my part, I am left-handed, and find that I smudge much less with a good fountain pen than with most roller-balls.  The idea that lefties don’t like fountain pens is a bit of a misconception in my experience — it’s just a matter of individual tastes either way, I think.

Comment: Starting in fourth (I think) grade we were required to use fountain pens in class through the end of sixth grade - at which point mine was placed firmly in the trash, never again to trouble me. Forgive me, oh my teachers, but the quality writing instrument of your day became the pointless anachronism of mine. But, hey - let's talk about calculators!!!! :-)

Comment: @mlk I love pencils too. They are pretty much like fountain pens, but much worse. The point is that when you write with a pencil or a fountain pen you have some feedback (if you know what I mean) and that makes your writing so perfectly satisfying. Bic pen (mentioned by someone) has no feedback and that makes it so bad.

Comment: @DeaneYang Deane, I will write an email to you. I do not want to write ads on a public forum.

Comment: Or instead of a fountain pen, this retractable rollerball pen covered in Einstein equations, [*Albert* model by Retro51.com](http://retro51.com/fwi_tor_vintage.html). [Pictures at GouletPens.com](https://www.gouletpens.com/collections/rollerball-pens/products/retro-51-tornado-rollerball-pen-albert?variant=12766371774507).

Comment: @DeaneYang, a very personal thing of course, I love Cross, beautifully made, not too expensive and last forever.

Comment: @user347489 Sure. I understand. Some people choose Big Mac over filet mignon. Tell me honestly: have you ever spent one hour trying to use a quality fountain pen?

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps a **slide rule** for your father. It is an instrument used for calculating exponents, roots, logarithms, etc. Slide rules predate calculators. Sadly, they are obsolete today. You can still find vintage slide rules at Etsy.

Below is an example.
[image]

Comment: I remember realizing that slide rules use a log scale to convert multiplication into addition. Such a nice application of an abstract fact for a concrete, practical purpose.

Comment: @NikWeaver I recently bought two slide rules and now I'm awaiting a third one in the post. A month before buying my first slide rule, I also got myself a few Soroban abacuses and a Sudoban abacus, as I was curious about them. I was intrigued by some Asians who worked natural logarithms on acabuses. And exponents and roots too. So I bought them. I am struggling to get the hang of them. Have you ever used them? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q62hQVfVGxU

Comment: I have a vintage slider rule after my grandfather who was an engineer. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use it, but I promised myself I will learn it.

Comment: Oooh. Great idea. I used to drool over slide rule catalogs.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty, what is a Sudoban abacus? (There are no google hits for that phrase other than your comment.) Meanwhile, abacus gifts sound more pleasing than a slide rule.

Comment: @MattF. probably soroban abacus (Japanese abacus)

Comment: @KingLogic : But Rita mentioned both Soroban and Sudoban as separate kinds.

Comment: @MattF. Sorry for my spelling mistake. It is suan pan or suanpan, a Chinese abacus. It is easier to use than soroban abacus which has two beads less on each column. I bought same model at this Amazon store. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07ZMQCS52/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @MattF. I also bought this book on suanpan acabus showing how to do multiplications & divisions, squares, cubes, roots, etc. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1460958810/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: This is the first model of soroban abacus that I bought. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07YZ59KR1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 Afterwards, I bought another soroban with two colours. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07LFYV4LJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Soroban acabus is taught in all schools in Asia and it makes kids insanely fast mental calculator. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gWzNjYx1bY

Answer (score 16):

One can also make a donation in the giftee's name, to something that mathematicians benefits from. Say, donate to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) (The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences), [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/), or Wikpedia.

Answer (score 16):

You may [adopt a polyhedron](https://www.polytopia.eu/en/) in their name!

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For mathematicians of a certain age, an old-fashioned chalkboard would be welcome. (This one, [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N7U3GSV/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N7U3GSV) is 17”x23” for only $12 at the moment.)

Answer (score 15):

In the vein of coffee-table books, I like

[Mathematicians: An Outer View of the Inner World](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-116/)

by Mariana Cook. It contains photographic portraits of 92 mathematicians, along with a short autobiographical essay on each one. The book was originally published in 2009 and many of the subjects are since deceased; as time goes on it serves increasingly as a record of a bygone age in mathematics.

Answer (score 15):

[image: IllusMath]

> *Illustrating Mathematics*,
> Ed. [Diana Davis](https://twitter.com/dianadavisphd/status/1320876017548955649), 2020.
> ISBN: 978-1-4704-6122-5.
> [AMS link](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-135).

Answer (score 15):

Several beautiful mathematical T-shirts could be found here:

https://www.tembelone.com

[image]

Comment: Nice, I like the rooted tree drawn in the upwards direction.

Comment: See also "p-adicts" T-shirt : https://www.bonfire.com/p-adicts/

Answer (score 12):

I have a personal, and highly idiosyncratic reply. My idea of a great Christmas gift would be a nice bottle of Scotch, or, as my daughter and son-in-law once gave me, a case of Guiness. Unlike a lot of mathematicians, when I stopped work for the day, week, or term, I really didn't want to do anything math related: puzzles; Rubik's cube; chess. I really dislike games of strategy.  My wife (also a mathematician) likes really hard Soduko and Kakuro. I prefer crosswords (New York Times, especially). I tell her that if I were going to work that hard with numbers, I would rather work on a research problem. It is for certain that I would not like a mathematical gift for Christmas, birthday, anniversary, or whatever. Maybe your Dad is a crossword fan?

I also dislike getting clothing for gifts as no one understands my likes, or dislikes. If my rant discourages you from getting a math gift, or any gift at all, I apologize. All in all, I would try to choose something safe, which of course is no help at all to you. Nonetheless, have a Happy Christmas, and I hope you get to celebrate with your Dad, circumstances permitting.

Comment: I think it safe to assume that the OP will weigh our suggestions against all the non-mathematical gift options that he/she can evaluate without our assistance.

Comment: @GordonRoyle - I completely agree.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's fine to get a technical book.  If he has two, your father can give away the one his kid didn't inscribe.

I don't know combinatorics well enough to identify the classics (although I do recall having been told that Lovasz's Combinatorial Problems & Exercises is one of the great books of the genre).   Instead I offer a few generic suggestions:

Aigner, Ziegler & Hoffman, Proofs From The Book.
Monastyrsky, Modern Mathematics In Light of The Fields Medal.

Answer (score 11):

https://math-sculpture.com/ carries a large variety of, well, varieties.

Answer (score 10):

I quite enjoy reading autobiographies or good scientific biographies of mathematicians (and other kinds of scientists) whose work has influenced the fields that I study. But I don't necessarily seek them out, preferring a casual opportunistic approach. I would be quite happy if someone were to give me such a book as a gift. It might be possible to please your father in a similar way.

Some extra research is required for this option though. Because the audience for biographies of this kinds is fairly narrow, many of them are out of print, if they even exist. Used book sellers are to be be consulted for good measure.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps he would like a hand-drawn portrait of his favorite mathematician (or himself!).  This is one of Kurt Gödel.  I'm a mathematician and artist and love to draw portraits of mathematicians.

[image: Portrait of Gödel]

Comment: It looks great. I like the contrast of different textures in the drawing. Did you draw this yourself?

Comment: @MoziburUllah thanks so much!  Yes, I drew it myself - it is just pen on paper.

Comment: You really should bring out a book or at least publish them on the web. I'd certainly buy a copy!

Comment: @MoziburUllah thanks!  I do have some posted here: https://erincarmody766.wixsite.com/mysite-3        And I would happily sell you one (this one even), I can send it to you - just email me erincarmody766@gmail.com.    And good idea on the portrait book!

Comment: They're great. I see you're a writer as well. I've always liked Alice so I bought the book to see how she got on in her further adventures.

Comment: @MoziburUllah great!  I have to admit I really like that book :) I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 9):

If your dad is currently teaching, perhaps a useful gift for him is a really comfortable chair (and desk maybe). Personally, since all my teaching duties this year have been done from home, I'm sitting the most part of the day, and I've been struggling with a lot of pain in my back.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to suggest [Joel David Hamkins'](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins) book [Proof and the Art of Mathematics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/proof-and-art-mathematics). My wife will give it to me this Christmas, and I couldn't look forward to it more.

Answer (score 7):

Just hint at their mathematical side, e.g. give them the complete collection of Joy Division albums. And maybe a matching T-shirt...
[Joy Division 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hibmc.png)

Comment: Do you mean this [Joy Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_Division)?

Comment: Yes. Of course, if the Dad prefers something more classical, perhaps a vinyl LP of the Sex Pistols first release, or perhaps something by Mr Iggy Stooge?

Answer (score 7):

An extravagant tiling related possibility:
[image]

[Image:Solarflare100](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RogerPenroseTileTAMU2010.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

I would say something related to tiling, so obviously https://mcescher.com/shop/ is the place.

Answer (score 6):

My school had [some of these](https://www.sbu.edu/academics/mathematics/zometool-resources) and I loved them.  [You can order them here](https://store.redhentoys.com/categories.aspx?Keyword=zome).  More stuff [here](http://geometrytoys.com/).

Also: lots of math sculptures at https://bathsheba.com .

Answer (score 5):

Treat him like a person, a math degree is a just a piece of paper, it doesn't define you.

Comment: I would say it definitely signals his interests and life experience.  And choosing a present for someone based on their interests and experiences is definitely a human thing to do (or so I have been told by humans).

Comment: You seem to be one of those people that just loves to get upset over anything someone does. Buying a gift based on someone's interests and passions is nice, and does not at all mean that you are not treating someone like a person....

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Lots of mathematicians have other interests!

Answer (score 5):

Although I am a programmer, I highly recommend this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Math-Book-Pythagoras-Milestones-Mathematics/dp/1402788290](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1402788290)

> Math’s infinite mysteries and beauty unfold in this follow-up to the best-selling The Science Book. Beginning millions of years ago with ancient “ant odometers” and moving through time to our modern-day quest for new dimensions, it covers 250 milestones in mathematical history. Among the numerous delights readers will learn about as they dip into this inviting anthology: cicada-generated prime numbers, magic squares from centuries ago, the discovery of pi and calculus, and the butterfly effect. Each topic gets a lavishly illustrated spread with stunning color art, along with formulas and concepts, fascinating facts about scientists’ lives, and real-world applications of the theorems.

I have a local publisher version with a different book cover and overall design. The book covers fairly complicated topics written in an easy-to-understand style targeting a broad range of readers.

[image]

I believe a guy with a Ph.D. in math can enjoy interesting math facts in a relaxing way.

Answer (score 5):

I myself work on graphs and studied quasiperiodic tilings, and I warmly recommend [XKCD and its goodies](https://store.xkcd.com/collections/everything), in particular the [volume 0 book](https://store.xkcd.com/collections/everything/products/xkcd-volume-0), the [log-scale height poster](https://store.xkcd.com/collections/everything/products/height-poster), and its other books!

[image: Height]

Answer (score 4):

Complex dynamics generates a wealth of fascinating fractals which are perfect for posters. So I would say a [Mandelmap poster](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MG2OAYI) can be a good gift.

Answer (score 3):

A book of interviews of famous mathematicians could be good. I have in mind particularly More Mathematical People, which I've gotten a lot of mileage from here at MathOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

A good red wine from Bodegas Langa (Spain)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think a twisty puzzle like a Rubik's Cube is a nice gift, especially if your recipient is interested in puzzles or group theory. I suggest avoiding the Rubik's brand cubes because those turn terribly and going for a Chinese company speedcube.  In my extremely limited experience with abstract algebra, I've found being able to see concretely commutators and generators is greatly rewarding and helps my intuition.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of choice from  Quasi periodic tiling designs for table mats by 3d printing ( choose a flexible plastic for rolling up thin sheet after breakfast ). Ask him for his  favorite tiling .. penrose, arabesque...

Answer (score 2):

It is common in Iran that students gift "[Rubaiyat Omar Khayyam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubaiyat_of_Omar_Khayyam)" that can be found in [Amazon easily](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Rubaiyat-Omar-Khayyam).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be hard to find a math book or a book about math that would be a sure fire gift for a mathematician. My suggestions are: (1) a classy chess set, and (2) an electronic keyboard, both of which speak to a "mathematician mind" in different ways. Two other possibilities: electronic chess set and electronic sudoku set.